# OnTouchListener for a view in Jelly Bean

Tags: android-layout, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a game Activity, which contains a SurfaceView that fills the whole screen.
The app is declared as fullscreen, and appears as such.

My SurfaceView has an OnTouchListener, which feeds a GestureDetector, with a functionality that works fine on most devices.
The listener is set as simply as:

```
surface.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

However, on Jelly Bean (Nexus 4) , touching the soft buttons (back, home, etc.) generates a touch event in coordinates that are irrelevant to my SurfaceView.

This currently generates weird behaviors.

I can workaround that by simply doing a check on touch events and see if they fit the surface size.

However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution - one that will just give me the touch events ONLY from my surface and not from those soft buttons.

This is also crucial in the case that some future devices do different variations of that (putting the soft buttons in the UPPER area, for example).